# php foreach loop from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array which I want to display in a foreach loop. I've been looking at lots of tutorials but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

This is my array and foreach loop:

```
$events = array( 
           array( Name => "First Event", 
                  Date => "12/13/14",
                  Time => "12:13"
                  Description => "event description"
                ),
           array( Name => "Second Event", 
                  Date => "12/13/14",
                  Time => "12:13",
                  Description => "event description"
                ),
           array( Name => "Third Event", 
                  Date => "12/13/14",
                  Time => "12:13"
                  Description => "event description"
                )
         );

foreach($events as $event) {
    echo "<div class=\"event\"><strong>";
    echo $event[Name];
    echo "</strong><em>";
    echo $event[Date] . " at " . $event[Time];
    echo "</em><div>";
    echo $event[Description];
    echo "</div></div>";
}
```

and here is how I want it to display:

```
<div class="event">
  <strong>Event Name</strong><em>Date at Time</em>
  <div>
    Description 
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help you could give. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your attempt at the `foreach`? We are happy to help you debug your code, but we aren't going to write it for you.

Comment: Basically, for each dim in your array, you nest a foreach loop. In your case, the first foreach gives you each array inside, and normally, you'd use an inner foreach on the array given by the first foreach to iterate over that array's contents. However, please see the answer below as it answers your problem specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys are missing quotes and Time => "12:13" missing comma "," at the end:

```
<?php
$events = array( 
           array( "Name" => "First Event", 
                  "Date" => "12/13/14",
                  "Time" => "12:13",
                  "Description" => "event description"
                ),
           array( "Name" => "Second Event", 
                  "Date" => "12/13/14",
                  "Time" => "12:13",
                  "Description" => "event description"
                ),
           array( "Name" => "Third Event", 
                  "Date" => "12/13/14",
                  "Time" => "12:13",
                  "Description" => "event description"
                )
         );

foreach($events as $event) {
?>
<div class="event">
    <strong><?php echo $event["Name"];?></strong><em><?php echo $event["Date"];?></em>
    <div><?php echo $event["Description"];?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Output**

**First Event** 12/13/14

event description

**Second Event** 12/13/14

event description

**Third Event** 12/13/14

event description

Answer (score 2):

The keys should be in quotes. E.g.: `'Name'` rather than `Name`

```
<?php foreach($events as $event): ?>
<div class="event">
   <strong><?php echo $event['Name'] ?></strong><em><?php echo $event['Date'] ?> at <?php echo $event['Time'] ?></em>
   <div>
    <?php echo $event['Description'] ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Yay thanks guys--I can finally post comments to questions now that I have > 50 points!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($events as $record) {

    $name = $record["name"];
    $date = $record["date"];
    $time = $record["time"];
    $description = $record["description"];

    print("
      // your html code with the variables here
    ");

}
```